# Ruby TinyInt(1)?

Tags: mysql, ruby

I have a mysql table defined with a status flag (which is a tinyint(1)).
However when I try check whether the value is true or false I seem to arrive at erroneous result. That is, it doesn't see the value as a legit true or value, but rather test's if it's not "nil" or alike - hence my "doesn't seem to work"

```
results.each_hash do |row|
 # What I tried

 # (a)
 if row['status'] 
    # do something - doesn't seem to work
 end

 # (b)
 if row['status'].to_i == 1
    # this seems correct
 end

 # (c)
 if row['status'] == false
   # doesn't seem to work
 end
end
```

What is the CORRECT approach for checking this value (tinyint(1)) as it should be a TrueClass or FalseClass in Ruby; however (c) doesn't work itself.

This is a reference I used - I'm assuming this should apply in rails and in ruby itself (unless ActiveRecord does the work) - http://www.orthogonalthought.com/blog/index.php/2007/06/mysql-and-ruby-on-rails-datatypes/

Comment: TinyINT get's interpreted in most languages C# etc to be "boolean", sorry and so does Ruby (it should see it as TRUECLASS or FALSECLASS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `active_record-3.2.13`, `abstract_mysql_adapter.rb` code line 96:

```
  # By default, the MysqlAdapter will consider all columns of type <tt>tinyint(1)</tt>
  # as boolean. If you wish to disable this emulation (which was the default
  # behavior in versions 0.13.1 and earlier) you can add the following line
  # to your application.rb file:
  #
  #   ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql[2]Adapter.emulate_booleans = false
```

Comment: Thank you - so Active Record consider it Bool and Ruby (standalone) considers it as plain int. Thanks

Comment: Ruby itself doesn't speak database.  If you're using ActiveRecord, the same data transformations should apply whether you're in Rails or just using the ActiveRecord gem in a non-Rails project.  If you use ActiveRecord outside of Rails, you might be missing some configuration that Rails provides.  If you're not using ActiveRecord at all (e.g. the mysql2 gem), you'll have to refer to that documentation.